# Is supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() working?

Tags: android

I'm having the following issue - I have to update `ActionBar` menu in my application, after some things happen. I use `ActionBarActivity` from appcompat library.

So, I call `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` function, but menu won't update. 
In debug mode I see, that onCreateOptionMenu method is calling, but menu not changed.

Am I doing something wrong? Or does it is `ActionBarActivity` issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After the system calls `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, it retains an instance of the Menu you populate and will not call `onCreateOptionsMenu()` again unless the menu is invalidated for some reason. However, you should use `onCreateOptionsMenu()` only to create the initial menu state and not to make changes during the activity lifecycle.

If you want to modify the options menu based on events that occur during the activity lifecycle, you can do so in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method. This method passes you the Menu object as it currently exists so you can modify it, such as add, remove, or disable items. (Fragments also provide an `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` callback.)

On Android 2.3.x and lower, the system calls `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` each time the user opens the options menu (presses the Menu button).

On Android 3.0 and higher, the options menu is considered to always be open when menu items are presented in the action bar. When an event occurs and you want to perform a menu update, you must call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to request that the system call `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.

for more details [click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Comment: when using support libraries, you can also call supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() to invalidate options from the menu.