# Updating Action Bar Menu Item due to AsyncTask result without delay

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-actionbar

I developed an Application which offers a detail view `Activity` (An activity which is called when clicking on a list item to display further information). This details `Activity` shall display a "favorite" start in the `Action Bar` (it is yellow if the item is a favorite, transparent if not - for this purpose I have to different image resources)

If i click the menu item, the item is added / removed form the user's favorites:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        ...
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_no_favorite) {
        ...
        new FavoriteTask(DetailsActivity.this).execute(user, item);
        mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_favorite).setVisible(true);
        mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_no_favorite).setVisible(false);
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_favorite) {
        ...
        new NoFavoriteTask(DetailsActivity.this).execute(user, item);
        mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_favorite).setVisible(false);
        mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_no_favorite).setVisible(true);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This works without any problem.

But if the user opens the detail view, the `Action Bar` menu item needs to be updated immediately, depending on if this item is already a favorite or not. I solved this issue by overriding onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.details_activity_actions, menu);
    this.mMenu = menu;
    ...
    new FetchFavortieStatusTask().execute(user, item);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

FavoriteStatusTask delivers a simple response (if the item is a favorite or not) and works like a charm. In onPostExecute, I update the menu item:

```
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (mMenu != null) {
            if (result.equals("no favorite")) {
                ...
                mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_favorite).setVisible(false);
                mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_no_favorite).setVisible(true);
            } else {
                ...
                mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_favorite).setVisible(true);
                mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_no_favorite).setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem that occurs: If I open a list item to get the detail view, the icon is changed after a delay of ~3 seconds or immediately if I touch the screen. The delay is definetly not caused by the `AsyncTask`, the result is delivered way faster. If I execute FetchFavortieStatusTask() in the end of the `Activity`'s onCreate method, it works as expected most of the time (but still, sometimes I do have this delay). Moving the `AsyncTask` to onPrepareOptionsMenu doesn't change anything.

Comment: I usually just call invalidateOptionsMenu() (or supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() for ActionBarActivity) and do all the visibility flipping in onCreateOptionsMenu(). Is that an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

ci_'s comment is a good hint but I had to adapt the solution in a bit different way (based on this answer: [Is supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356611/is-supportinvalidateoptionsmenu-working))

I call the AsyncTask in onCreate() now and in its onPostExecute method I only set a member variable mIsFavorite to true or false and then execute supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() which calles onPrepareOptionsMenu a second time (but not onCreateOptionsMenu!). This means that I have to update the menu items in onPrepareOptionsMenu, based on the value of mIsFavorite.

Comment: I have to correct myself: The problem still occurs. It seems to be related to the transition when calling this Activity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318415/when-using-overridependingtransition-modifying-ui-views-in-the-called-activity