# When using overridePendingTransition, modifying UI views in the called activity is very slow

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-animation, android-transitions

a few days ago, I had a problem with updating an `Action Bar` menu icon based on the result of an `AsyncTask`: [Updating Action Bar Menu Item due to AsyncTask result without delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29239804/updating-action-bar-menu-item-due-to-asynctask-result-without-delay)

Now I realized that this problem is not at all related to an `AsyncTask` or an `Action Bar`. The problem occurs as well if I want to change a `TextView` or any other `View`.

After some time of trial and error I realized that the problem is caused by overridePendingTransition which I use in the `Activity` which calls the second `Activity` (where I want to change the icon):

First `Activity` (in an onItemClick method):

```
@Override
   public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
   ...
   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
   ...
   startActivityForResult(intent, anyValue);
   getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.no_animation);
}
```

The animation looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

And this is how the AsyncTask (onPostExecute) of the second Activity looks like:

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(String result) {
   super.onPostExecute(result);
   if (mMenu != null) {
      if (result.equals("no favorite")) {
      ...
      mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_favorite).setVisible(false);
      mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_no_favorite).setVisible(true);
   } else {
      ...
      mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_favorite).setVisible(true);
      mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_no_favorite).setVisible(false);
   }
}
```

As explained, instead of switching between two menu icons, you could also use one TextView and setting the text based on the result - the problem remains.

Do you know how I can change the animation without having this weird delay in my second `Activity`?

Answer (score 0):

Check your **integer.xml** file
Make the value of **config_shortAnimTime** smaller according to your needs.
Its in milliseconds.
*Prefer making it 1000 (1 sec).*

Comment: The default value is already set to 200 ms. But decreasing it to 100 or even increasing it to 1000 doesn't change anything, the problem is not related to the animation itself, it occurs later in the new Activity.